# Unable to detect 'Add Extension' popup in chrome web store [playwright / puppeteer / selenium]

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension, automation, playwright

I am using playwright to install an extension from chrome web store. The problem is that I am unable to detect the Add extension popup that appears on clicking the 'Add to chrome' button

[image: Add Extension popup when adding a chrome extension]

My code is:

```
const getStoreBuild = async () => {
  const browser = await chromium.launchPersistentContext(testDataDist, {
    channel: 'chrome',
    headless: false,
    acceptDownloads: true,
  })
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  page.on('dialog', async (dialog) => {
    await dialog.accept();
  })
  await page.goto('https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/arc-cookie-exchange/apcedakaoficjlofohhcmkkljehnmebp');
  const addToChrome = page
    .locator('div[aria-label="Add to Chrome"]')
    .first();
  await addToChrome.click({timeout: 10000});
  const removeBtn = page.locator('div[aria-label="Remove from Chrome"]');
  await removeBtn.waitFor();
}

await getStoreBuild()
```

After clicking on the addToChrome button, the code simply moves ahead and waits for the removeBtn without going inside the page.on() function. It seems that the popup isn't a dialog. That's why the code never enters `page.on()` function. I tried replacing the code for `page.on('dialog')...` with this

```
page.on('download', async (download)=>{
  await download.saveAs('chrome-extension.zip')
})
```

but it doesn't work either. Here also, the code never enters the `page.on()` method.

What I am looking for is to click on the 'Add extension' button so that the extension downloads.

Any idea how to recognize the 'Add extension' button?

Note: The extension url mentioned in the above code is just a sample. In reality, I am trying to install the prod version of the extension of my company so that we can run tests on prod. The code is the same, though.I have not used any variables in this question to simplify the code.

Comment: I think google defines the chrome web store as a special place so I don't think it will work.

Comment: @NorioYamamoto - even if it is somehow not a "dialog", I am trying to find what it is exactly. It seems like it could be a download popup if not a dialog by definition. 
Once I know, maybe I can try and find a way. 
If not possible at all, then will look at a different (albeit hacky) solution of somehow getting the .crx file and using it to download the extension

Comment: `await page.keyboard.press('ArrowLeft');`
`await page.keyboard.press("Enter")`;

Comment: I tried using the keyboard navigation but it didn't work. @jkalandarov did it work for you this way?

Comment: @RahulSingh Hey, did you find any solution to accept the permission?

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't get this working. I am now thinking of using a node package (if such a page exists) that can help download the extension package and store it locally. But, no progress yet

Answer (score 0):

don't know if it's still relevant, but you are doing it wrong.
Instead of installing the extension, provide the path to it, and launch Playwright with the correct `launchPersistentContext`.

On [this thread](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/11108) you can see how it is do. Or check [docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/chrome-extensions).

Or in a nutshell:

```
import { test as base, expect, chromium, firefox, webkit } from '@playwright/test';
import path from 'path';

export const test = base.extend({
  context: async ({ browserName }, use) => {
    const browserTypes = { chromium, firefox, webkit }
    const extensionPath = '/some/path/'
    const context = await browserTypes[browserName].launchPersistentContext('/some/dir', {
        headless: false,
        args: [
            `--disable-extensions-except=${extensionPath}`,
            `--load-extension=${extensionPath}`,
        ]
    })

test.only('basic test', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('https://playwright.dev/');
});
```